# (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) no es compatible con el tipo de control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer). ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, reportviewer

tengo el siguiente problema a la hora de cargar mi siguiente archivo ASPX con un ReportViewer Item adentro; He leido que puede ser referido a la version en el Assembly del encabezado del archivo aspx más no he encontrado como corregirlo

***La clase base incluye el campo 'ReportViewer2', pero su tipo (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) no es compatible con el tipo de control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer).***

```
Error de código fuente:


Línea 33:                                 <td class="TamCol3"></td>
Línea 34:                                  <td style="text-align: center;">                                  
Línea 35:                                       <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana"
Línea 36:                                             WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%" Height="750px"
Línea 37:                                             ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False"
```

---

[ErrorImagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glEsT.png)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reporte.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Reporte" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>


             <asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server">

        </asp:ScriptManager>
        </div>

        <br />  
        <br />


            <div>

                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <table style="width:120%;margin:0 auto">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="TamCol3"></td>
                                 <td style="text-align: center;">                                  
                                      <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana"
                                            WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%" Height="750px"
                                            ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False"
                                            ShowZoomControl="False" 
                                            ToolBarItemBorderColor="White" 
                                            ToolBarItemBorderStyle="None" 
                                            BackColor="#F5F6F7" 
                                            BorderColor="Gray"
                                            ShowRefreshButton="false" 
                                            BorderStyle="None" 
                                            BorderWidth="1px" 
                                            DocumentMapWidth="100%">
                                            <LocalReport ReportPath="Report1.rdlc">
                                            </LocalReport>
                                      </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                                     </td>  
                            </tr>
                        </table>


                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Reporte.aspxcs [  No tengo nada implementado aún pero por si es requerido ]:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Reporte : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataSet Dtset;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        void fMuestraReporte(String idSolicitud)
        {
            try
            {
                string sNomReporte = "RptVerTelefonica.rdlc";
                ReportDataSource Rd = new ReportDataSource();
                Dtset = new DataSet();
              //  Dtset = Session[]
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: podrias fijarte si el ReportView que agregaste sea para web y no en WindowForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andres prueba ingresando en tu page aspx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

y en tu Web.Config lo siguiente:

```
<compilation debug="true">

<assemblies>

<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

<add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/></assemblies>

<buildProviders>

<add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

</buildProviders>

</compilation>
```